# boto3 check for new SQS messages in the background

Tags: python, amazon-sqs, boto3

I have the following python script that polls sqs and processes any messages that get pushed to the queue. I run `python process.py` in terminal and see that it processing as it should.

What is the best or preferred method to have this script run in the background?

```
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region( REGION , aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
q = conn.get_queue( PROCESS_QUEUE )

def process_message(m):
    # do some processing
    # q.delete_message(m)

while 1:
    q.set_message_class(RawMessage)
    m = q.read(wait_time_seconds=20)

    if m:
        print 'processing...'
        process_message(m, q)

    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bash` capabilites here.

**Quick and dirty :**

Running `python process.py &` will launch it as a background process.

Have a look at `nohup`, which stores the process logs etc.

**Clean way to do this :**

Using `supervisor`, it's some kind of service manager, which permits you to run daemons in the background.

Look at the [docs](http://supervisord.org/), setting it up isn't long, comment if you need help.